# Can I use football player names, team names, stats... in my app/website?

Tags: copyright

I am planning on building app/website where I will display football player names, their teams, and stats about them(goals, assistances, etc..) Is this legal or I need a license. Also I will use profile photos for each player. Can I also use team logos to refer where the players are ?

I saw a post that said that facts is not copyrightable, but maybe, I cannot use names of football players teams. Any help or strategy is welcomed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need copyright permission for a blog](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/do-i-need-copyright-permission-for-a-blog)

Comment: just a part of what I was asking, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking:

If you're simply reporting facts and figures you can use player names and team names, goals, assistances, logos etc. That's fair use. The media does it 'all the time'.

If you're making a game it's likely you will need permission to use player names and team names, logos etc. It's unlikely to be fair use and the player names, team names, logos etc are likely to be trademarked and only usable under licence.

In any case you want to avoid it appearing to be produced, sponsored or endorsed by the league, team or player - unless of course you have permission to say so.

Comment: So if I am reporting facts there is no way they can't shutdown my app event there are player images and team logos, right?

Comment: @Ángellangdon Generally and legally speaking you have a fair use defence if you are merely reporting facts. In practice a platform might operate a "shutdown first, investigate second and perhaps apologise later" policy on receipt of a complaint. If you want advice for your specific circumstances consider consulting a copyright lawyer and the platform.